# Accidentally uninstalled “apt” fro Ubuntu 18.04. How do I reinstall it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, apt, aptitude

I deleted apt-get by accident, and now I'm having problem reinstalling it.

Here is what I did

```
dpkg -r apt (uninstalled apt-get)
```

I tried to download apt.deb files and install back with

```
sudo dpkg -i apt_1.2.32ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
```

It gives me this error:

```
Selecting previously unselected package aptitude:amd64.
(Reading database ... 200534 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack aptitude_0.8.10-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking aptitude:amd64 (0.8.10-6ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of aptitude:amd64:
 aptitude:amd64 depends on aptitude-common (= 0.8.10-6ubuntu1).
 aptitude:amd64 depends on libboost-filesystem1.65.1.
 aptitude:amd64 depends on libboost-iostreams1.65.1.
 aptitude:amd64 depends on libboost-system1.65.1.
 aptitude:amd64 depends on libcwidget3v5.
 aptitude:amd64 depends on libncursesw5 (>= 6).
 aptitude:amd64 depends on libsigc++-2.0-0v5 (>= 2.8.0).
 aptitude:amd64 depends on libxapian30.

dpkg: error processing package aptitude:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 aptitude:amd64
```

Then I tried this :

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all apt_1.2.32ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
```

It gives me this output:

```
Selecting previously unselected package apt:amd64.
(Reading database ... 200540 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack apt_1.2.32ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apt:amd64 (1.2.32ubuntu0.1) ...
dpkg: apt:amd64: dependency problems, but configuring anyway as you requested:
 snapd (2.48+18.04) breaks apt (<< 1.6.3) and is installed.
  Version of apt:amd64 to be configured is 1.2.32ubuntu0.1.

Setting up apt:amd64 (1.2.32ubuntu0.1) ...

Configuration file '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01-vendor-ubuntu', does not exist on system.
Installing new config file as you requested.

Configuration file '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove', does not exist on system.
Installing new config file as you requested.

Configuration file '/etc/cron.daily/apt-compat', does not exist on system.
Installing new config file as you requested.

Configuration file '/etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal', does not exist on system.
Installing new config file as you requested.

Configuration file '/etc/logrotate.d/apt', does not exist on system.
Installing new config file as you requested.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal: 14: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal: apt-config: Exec format error
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal: 18: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal: apt-config: Exec format error
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal: 49: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal: apt-config: Exec format error
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/apt-daily-upgrade.timer → /lib/systemd/system/apt-daily-upgrade.timer.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/apt-daily.timer → /lib/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
```

Now when I'm trying to use

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It gives me this:

```
/usr/bin/apt-get: 1: /usr/bin/apt-get: ELF: not found
/usr/bin/apt-get: 1: /usr/bin/apt-get: @8�@8: not found
/usr/bin/apt-get: 2: /usr/bin/apt-get: ����: not found
/usr/bin/apt-get: 3: /usr/bin/apt-get: : not found
/usr/bin/apt-get: 3: /usr/bin/apt-get: cannot open ½���������hI��p�: No such file
rm�: not foundet: 3: /usr/bin/apt-get: c
/usr/bin/apt-get: 4: /usr/bin/apt-get: �7��: not found
�F�'�: /usr/bin/apt-get: 
                   �
                     �J
n\����          \
Y[#��   �d��=
           �: not found
/usr/bin/apt-get: 6: /usr/bin/apt-get: �C��+: not found
/usr/bin/apt-get: 16: /usr/bin/apt-get: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: sudo apt install apt 

Comment: Odd. I have [posted an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1607582/167207) already which I believe will solve your problem, but I looked at your question again and you say you did this `sudo dpkg -i apt_1.2.32ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb` but then look at the messages you got afterwards that reference `aptitude_0.8.10-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb`. I assume you attempted to install `aptitude` and then `apt`? They do similar things but are 100% different packages.

Answer (score 1):

### You are attempting to install the Ubuntu 16.04 version of `apt` and not the Ubuntu 18.04 version of `apt`.

Look at this page for [`apt`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/apt) ([1.2.32ubuntu0.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/apt)). Note that the breadcrumbs for the URL in the page is:

> » Ubuntu » Packages » xenial (16.04LTS) » admin » apt

That’s clearly the Ubuntu 16.04 version. But you are running Ubuntu 18.04. So you need to get [`apt`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/apt) ([1.6.12ubuntu0.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/apt)) which can be [found here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/apt). Again, look at the breadcrumbs for the URL in the page:

> » Ubuntu » Packages » bionic (18.04LTS) » admin » apt

Download it [directly from here](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.6.12ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) and just run this command:

```
sudo dpkg --install apt_1.6.12ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
```

And you should be solid.